# Group Ruby array by specific values

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array and I'd like to select only the elements between two specified values.

For example, I have an array that looks like this:

```
a = ["don't want", "don't want", "Start", "want", "want", "Stop", "don't want", "Start", "want", "Stop", "don't want"]
```

I want to call a method on the a array that captures the elements between "Start" and "Stop" (that includes the "Start" and "Stop" elements).  The resulting array should look like this:

```
[["Start", "want", "want", "Stop"], ["Start", "want", "Stop"]]
```

I could not find a method like this, so I tried writing one:

```
class Array
  def group_by_start_and_stop(start = "Start", stop = "Stop")
    main_array = []
    sub_array = []

    group_this_element = false

    each do |e|
      group_this_element = true if e == start

      sub_array << e if group_this_element

      if group_this_element and e == stop
        main_array << sub_array
        sub_array = []
        group_this_element = false
      end
    end

    main_array
  end
end
```

This works, but it seems perhaps unnecessarily verbose to me.  So I have two questions:  Does a similar method already exist?  If not, are there ways to make my group_by_start_and_stop method better?

Comment: What about nested delimiters (`['Start', 'want', 'Start', 'want', 'Stop', 'Stop']`)? Is that a Start/Stop inside another Start/Stop, overlapping intervals, or invalid?

Comment: In that case, I think I'd want everything between the "Start" and the first "Stop".  Then it would start again.  So, given your example, I'd want the result to be: [["Start", "want", "Start", "want", "Stop"]]

Answer (score 7):

That's the perfect example where a flip-flop is useful!

```
a.select {|i| true if (i=="Start")..(i=="Stop")}.slice_before("Start").to_a
```

Not super known feature, but pretty cool nonetheless! Use it together with `slice_before`, and you get exactly what you want!

Comment: Greate decision!

a.select {|i| true if (i=="Start")..(i=="Stop") } 

would be enough

Comment: I like that condition, didn't know that was possible! still, the result is not the expected result, You still have to present it as an array of arrays.

Comment: OK! I fixed that with `slice_before`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions.  I found that this one worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.each_with_index.select{|s, i| s.eql?("Start") or s.eql?("Stop")}
                 .map{|s, i| i}
                 .each_slice(2)
                 .map{|s, f| a[s..f]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.inject [] do |m, e|
  if e == 'Start'
    @state = true
    m << []
  end
  m.last << e if @state
  @state = false if e == 'Stop'
  m
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.join('^').scan(/Start.*?Stop/).map { |x| x.split('^') }
=> [["Start", "want", "want", "Stop"], ["Start", "want", "Stop"]]
```

The symbol *^* seems to be rare so maybe it won't mix with another original symbols.

Answer (score 0):

`:dummy` below is to ensure that the first chunk of the return from `slice_before` is what you do not want.

```
p [pres = :dummy, *a].slice_before{|e|
  prev, pres = pres, e
  prev == "Stop" or pres == "Start"
}
.select.with_index{|_, i| i.odd?}
# => => [["Start", "want", "want", "Stop"], ["Start", "want", "Stop"]]
```